# Xcode Storyboard broken since iOS 13 / Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios13, xcode11

Since the update to Xcode 11 and iOS 13 the storyboard of my app is broken. This means that all `rect` elements in this file have wrong dimensions. Either height or width is a bit to high. Leading to the issue, that the UI is broken on the iPhone. When I try to fix them it works fine till I reopen the storyboard file the next time. Then Xcode prints 'indexing...' and after a couple of seconds all dimensions are wrong again.

I have added a screenshot showing the issue. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Are your ***constraints*** changing? Or, did you not use constraints, and so your storyboard is defaulting to a different "View As: device?

Comment: I did not use any constraints. The whole UI is using the autoresizing options. Even if I change back to "View As: iPhone XS" the wrong dimensions still exist.

Comment: Difficult to know what might be going on... If you edit your question and add the source of your Storyboard, we can take a look.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but should I add the whole storyboard or just the header and some of the broken lines?

Comment: Whole storyboard.